# Retrofit2 & Room : работа с потоками

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-threads

Как добавить строку/строки в базу? Для работы с сетью используется Retrofit, с базой - Room. Если добавлять прямо в методе `onResponse` ,то  возвращает исключение: нельзя в основном потоке,что логично.

```
pageCall.enqueue(new Callback<Page>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Page> call, @NonNull Response<Page> response) {
                   AppDatabase
                       .getInstance(MainActivity.this)
                       .getRepoDao()
                       .insertText(new Text(response.body().content,1));
                   }
```

Читал, гугл рекомендует использовать LiveData,только не совсем понял как это сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конкретно как рекомендует Google - они делают абстракцию над ответом [Resource с разными состояниями](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#addendum), и отдают его по ходу общения либо из сети (с сохранением), либо из базы.

Соответственно они делают спец интерфейс NetworkBoundResource реализуя который вы определяете как конкретно вы сохраняете данные в базу. (Это может быть и Room и другие реализации.

Конкретно в [их примере, версия на Java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/rc1/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.java#L75) они делают вызов на отдельном потоке используя специальную абстракцию AppExecutors (она нужна чтобы подменять например при тестировании)

```
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            appExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {
                saveCallResult(processResponse(response));
                appExecutors.mainThread().execute(() ->
                        // we specially request a new live data,
                        // otherwise we will get immediately last cached value,
                        // which may not be updated with latest results received from network.
                        result.addSource(loadFromDb(),
                                newData -> setValue(Resource.success(newData)))
                );
            });
        }
```

Если будете использовать LiveData обратите внимание на то что вам надо будет использовать [postValue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#postvalue) чтобы отдать данные на главный поток из бэкграунда. Не суть важно будете вы использовать Async Task или другую абстракцию над тредами, но сохранение и работу с данными лучше делать на другом потоке.

Для вашего случая вы можете указать что вы хотите получать вызов на другом потоке, опять же используя специальный executor. Делать это над при конструировании запроса, например используя SingleThreadExecutor ([отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41370867/5892568))

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(/* your url */)
        .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
        // other builder options...
        .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

Эту задачу можно решить с помощью `RxJava` поддержка которой есть как у `Retrofit` так и у `Room`. Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
//возврщает Observable<DataFromApiClass>
retrofitInterfaceInstance.getDataFromApi()
    //преобразует данные в Observable в результат вызова метода записи в БД
    .map(data -> databaseInstance.getDao().insertData(data))
    //указываем поток для запуска операций
    .subscribeOn(Schedullers.io())
    //указываем поток для получения результата операций
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedullers.mainThread())
    //собственно запускаем операции для получения результата
    .subscribe()
```